# instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier in Storyboard

Tags: ios, storyboard, instantiation, tabbar

I've made a tabbar controller with two views (standard setup from the template). First view is accessing an array within an dataController object. When I tap to the second view on the tabbar, I want the dataController reference to be set on the second viewController's dataController property.

I use call

```
SecondViewController *vc = [[self storyboard] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SecondViewController"];
vc.dataController = self.dataController;
```

However, when I call my countArrayObjects on the secondViewController's dataController property, I always get 0 back - eventhough there should be objects in the array and I can't figure out why?

I've set the identifier on the secondViewController in MainStoryBoard and I have no crashes, the property just isn't set (I think).

For testing purposes I call the instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier from a simple button, before tapping on to the secondView. And I call the countArrayObjects from viewDidLoad on secondViewController.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm... I was having the same problem. At the moment, the only way I got around this is to test for the views superview being nil - which as its accessing the view selector of the class fires up the view did load event...

both of us are doing something wrong here though...

This is the test code I wrote...

```
SummaryViewController *sc = [self.childViewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
if(sc.view.superview == nil) sc.checkInTime.alpha = 0;
//-- by inspecting the value, it will call the viewDidLoad method of the controller.
```

It works, but it's wrong.